# A package contains 12 yogurts with 4 different flavors. What is the probability of one of each?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A package contains 12 yogurts that look the same on the outside, 3 of
>   which being of apple, 3 of kiwi, 3 of orange and 3 of melon.
>
> Extracting 4 random yogurts from the package what is the probability
>   of taking an yogurt of each flavor?

I did $$\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{12} = (\frac{3}{12})^4 = \frac{1}{256}$$

But my book says the answer is $\frac{9}{55}$.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you are trying to fix an order of the flavors.  $\{Apple, kiwi, orange, melon\}$, say.  If so, then it should read $\frac 3{12}\times \frac 3{11}\times \frac 3{10}\times \frac 39$.  But there are $4!$ possible orders....

Comment: @lulu Why 4! possible orders?

Comment: Four possibilities for the first, then three for the second, then two for the third.  That's $4\times 3\times 2=4!$

Comment: @lulu Ah, I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. When you take the first yogurt, the second one is chosen among $11$ yogurts. Moreover you do not care about the order in which you pick the $4$ flavours.